# how to share contact via bluetooth in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, contacts, android-contacts

i implement one application in that i am showing phone contacts list(like screenshot) when click on list activity i am calling Intent.ACTION_SEND for sending contact or business card via bluetooth but it is not working i am struck here please help me....

here is my code:
...................

```
public class GetContactsDemo extends Activity {
     Button btnImport,btnAdd;
     ListView list;
      LazyAdapter adap;

    ArrayList<String> Cnames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> CphoneNo = new ArrayList<String>();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         btnImport = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnimport);
         btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
         list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

   //to import contacts      
         btnImport.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {![enter image description here][2]

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                readContacts();

                 adap = new LazyAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                 list.setAdapter(adap);
            }
        });

   //to add contact
         btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent addcontact = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddingNewContactActivity.class);
                startActivity(addcontact);

            }
        });
         list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+arg2, 1000).show();

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("com.android.contacts/raw_contacts/2");
                 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                 // i.setType("image/jpeg");  
                 i.setType("text/x-vcard");  
                  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); 
                  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Contact"));

            }
        });

    }

    public void readContacts(){
         ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
         Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

         if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);
                    Log.e("name","name-->"+name);
                    Cnames.add(name);


                    // get the phone number
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                           new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                          String phone = pCur.getString(
                                 pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                          System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                          Log.e("phone","phone-->"+phone);
                          CphoneNo.add(phone);

                    }
                    pCur.close();


  class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        Context mcontext;
        LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public LazyAdapter(Context context) {
            this.mcontext = context;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return Cnames.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0)
    {
        return arg0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup arg2) 
    {
        View vi = v;
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate, null);
        TextView txt = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        TextView txt1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtphoneno);

        txt.setText(Cnames.get(position));
        txt1.setText(CphoneNo.get(position));
        return vi;
    }
}

}
```

Thanks in advance

[image]